# Sort associative 3d array by count of children in each row descending, then by first level keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array of IP networks

```
<?php
$array = array(
    '217.192' => array(
        array(
            'ip' => '217.192.133.52',
            'id' => '1',
        ),
        array(
            'ip' => '217.192.98.111',
            'id' => '2',
        ),
    ),
    '21.170' => array(
        array(
            'ip' => '21.170.171.23',
            'id' => '3',
        ),
        array(
            'ip' => '21.170.212.22',
            'id' => '4',
        ),
    ),
    '148.11' => array(
        array(
            'ip' => '148.11.11.12',
            'id' => '5',
        ),
        array(
            'ip' => '148.11.122.33',
            'id' => '6',
        ),
        array(
            'ip' => '148.11.22.89',
            'id' => '7',
        ),
    ),
    '72.1' => array(
        array(
            'ip' => '72.1.98.9',
            'id' => '8',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I need to output this array ordering by count AND sort by subnetwork (key of array).

`arsort($array)` doesn't work like I want.

I need 
148.11, 21.170, 217.192, 72.1 AND inside these so sort ips...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sortHelper(array $a, array $b) {
    $aCnt = count($a);
    $bCnt = count($b);
    if ($aCnt == $bCnt) {
        return 0;
    } else if ($aCnt > $bCnt) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

uasort($array, 'sortHelper');

// UPDATE: sort inside by IP

function ipSortHelper(array $a, $b) {
    $aIp = ip2long($a['ip']);
    $bIp = ip2long($b['ip']);
    if ($aIp == $bIp) {
        return 0;
    } else if ($aIp < $bIp) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

foreach ($array as $prefix => $group) {
    uasort($group, 'ipSortHelper');
    $array[$prefix] = $group;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce total function calls and avoid an anonymous function, use `array_multisort()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZEtDR))

```
array_multisort(
    array_map('count', $array), // rule 1
    SORT_DESC,                  // rule 1 direction
    array_keys($array),         // rule 2
    $array                      // affect original array
);
var_export($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a "custom sort function": http://www.php.net/usort and write the logic for sorting yourself.